# Creating an instance in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three models where a basiccase has a form. Basic case can create a new form.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basiccases
end

class Basiccase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :form3_c      
end

class Form3C < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :basiccases
end
```

I want to create an instance of form 3c in the form3c controller. Can any one explain me how I can carry the basiccase_id to the form3c controller to set the foreign key attribute.
I can set the value using @basiccase.build_form3_c but I'm not sure how I can get the basiccase_id from the basiccase.

Comment: Err, do you mean Form3c `belongs_to :basiccase`?

Comment: why is your class Basiccase > has_one :basiccases? Also, are you using attr_accessible in your models? If so, don't forget to add in your foreign key to that list (or declare it in your controller (prevent mass assignment)).